# How to install the standalone Nvidia driver on linux mint?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, linux-mint

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers on Linux Mint 17 using the .run file that is downloaded from Nvidia website. I receive this error:

```
 ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
             installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
             THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
             download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I googled and I can see that I should disable X server and then enter some codes. The fist step of the solution is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but this gives me a black blank screen. There's no space or area to enter codes or something like that. There's no pointer. Just a black screen. I can return back to graphics mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
How can I solve the black screen issue to be able to solve the Nvidia driver error?

Note: I would like to install the standalone drivers. I don't want to use the internet for some reasons.

Comment: why arent you using the ppa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).  This prevents the X server from starting.
2. Drop to a root shell prompt:

   [image: Ubuntu Recovery Menu]
3. Remount the root file system to allow writes:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
4. Run the command to install the standalone NVIDIA graphics driver.